# Does every projectile land with a vertical velocity only?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile

A projectile when thrown with any velocity at any angle with horizontal has two components of velocity i.e. Vertical and horizontal (out of which the projectile may exhibit either of them or both throughout the journey). Is it necessary that at the landing instant the projectile possesses only a vertical component of velocity? Assuming the projectile to be a point object.

Comment: There is no force in the horizontal direction so the horizontal velocity wont change,it will be same the whole journey even when the projectile lands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, upon landing, a projectile can have both vertical and horizontal velocity. In fact, disregarding air resistance or other external forces, the final horizontal velocity will be identical to the initial horizontal velocity. Imagine throwing a ball across a field - the ball doesn't stop dead once it lands, it will continue to bounce and roll away at some horizontal velocity.

Comment: Please elaborate. What determines if the projectile is going to land with both velocities or any one of the component?

Comment: I mean is it so that since there is no horizontal force, the projectile has to have a horizontal landing velocity component?

Comment: @Swami Yes, there is no horizontal force, so the horizontal speed is unchanged.